# How can i move certain files/classes/tests into a new Visual Studio project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest

I just started learning C#.

For now, I'm writing most things in the same Project by creating new classes for each thing I want to do. For most of the classes I wrote MSTest unit tests.

Since I just started a lot of the files are pure garbage with little utility value but I have some classes and tests that I would like to keep and move into a clean project so that I can reuse them.

Is there an easy method to extract classes and their tests into a new project without manually copy/pasting them?

Comment: you can create the project and then move the .cs files u want in the file system. then just add them to the new project and remove from the old project where it was..

Comment: Yep, just click and drag the files in visual studio.